# Image positioning over an included html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to pin an image to the top right corner over some included content.

```
<div class="panel-body helpContent">
   <img src="/images/myImage.png" class="beta" />
   <jsp:include page='<%="includes/" + thisFile +".html"%>' flush="true" />
</div>
```

The image is just a small little badge in the corner, about 150px x 150px.

The beta class looks like this:

```
.beta{
   position:absolute;
   top:0px;
   right:15px;}
```

Problem is that the image sits on top of the content in some of the HTML files. Not all of them, mind you. But the ones with a really long header at the top.

What I'd like is for the html content to wrap so it doesn't hit it. I could do that if I included the image in every single HTML file but I'd rather just include it once if possible.

Is there a creative solution to this that doesn't require the image on every page?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: Use `position: relative;` on the container you want

Comment: @Brewal position:absolute will be fine for the image, use width of container in terms of % and `max-width:90%` or near-about on your container

Comment: @SachinKanungo I was not talking about the image

Comment: You should provide screenshots or try to make a jsFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried float right?

```
<div class="panel-body helpContent">
    <img src="/images/myImage.png" class="beta" />
    <jsp:include page='<%="includes/" + thisFile +".html"%>' flush="true" />
    <div class="clear"> </div>
</div>

.beta {
  float:right;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: This comes very close but now the image isn't pinned 100% to the right; there appears to be some padding on the top and right.

Comment: Forget it, my bad. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="panel-body helpContent">
    <jsp:include page='<%="includes/" + thisFile +".html"%>' flush="true" />
    <img src="/images/myImage.png" class="beta" />
</div>
```

and

```
.beta{
     position:absolute;
     top:0px;
     z-index: 1000;
     right:15px;}
```

Comment: This still keeps it overlapping the content; you're setting the z-index as the top-most layer.